# - Open Gradle wrapper settings, change `distributionUrl` property to use compatible Gradle version and reload the project

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Error when creating new empty activity / project:

```
 - Open Gradle wrapper settings, change `distributionUrl` property to use compatible Gradle version and reload the project
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To resolve this error, open the gradle-wrapper.properties page or click the link in the console

second line:

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
```

change it to

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.6-bin.zip
```